# Update NSLayoutConstraint on parent View

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

How can I change/update a Constraint on a parent view.

What I have tried using a CodeBlock:

```
//
//  CollectionViewController.m
//  FloatingButton
//

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "MyCollectionViewCell.h"

#import "FloatingView.h"

#define CircleWidthAndHight 80

@interface CollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController{
    FloatingView *floatingView;
    CGRect rectOrigin;
    NSLayoutConstraint *hightConstraint;

}

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = YES;

//    CGFloat hightOfFloatingView = self.collectionView.frame.size.height - (self.collectionView.frame.size.height - 100);
//    CGFloat yPositionOfFloatingView = self.collectionView.frame.size.height - (hightOfFloatingView + 10);


    floatingView = [[FloatingView alloc] initWithCircleSize:CircleWidthAndHight];
    floatingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    __block id myself = self;
    floatingView.compare = ^{
        [myself showFloatingButtons];

    };

    [self.view addSubview:floatingView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:floatingView];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Register cell classes
//    [self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)createTabBar{

}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [self setConstraints];
}

- (void) showFloatingButtons{

    hightConstraint.constant = 200;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

//    [self.view removeConstraint:hightConstraint];
//
//    hightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
//                       constraintWithItem:floatingView
//                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
//                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
//                       toItem:nil
//                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
//                       multiplier:1.0
//                       constant:CircleWidthAndHight +200];
//    
//    
//    
//    [self.view addConstraint:hightConstraint];


}

- (void)setConstraints{

    floatingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:floatingView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:self.view
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                              multiplier:1.0
                              constant:CircleWidthAndHight]];

    hightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:floatingView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:nil
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                              multiplier:1.0
                              constant:CircleWidthAndHight +20];



    [self.view addConstraint:hightConstraint];
//    floatingView.parentHightConstraint = hightConstraint;

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:floatingView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *yConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:floatingView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraint:yConstraint];

//    floatingView.parentYConstraint = yConstraint;

    [floatingView setConstraints];
}



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.label.text = @"Hello there!";

    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 100);
}

#pragma mark ScrollView

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
//    CGRect collBounds = self.collectionView.bounds;
//    CGRect floatFrame = floatingView.frame;
//    floatingView.frame = CGRectMake(rectOrigin.origin.x,
//                                    rectOrigin.origin.y + collBounds.origin.y,
//                                    floatFrame.size.width,
//                                    floatFrame.size.height);
//    
//    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:floatingView];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

/*
// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Uncomment these methods to specify if an action menu should be displayed for the specified item, and react to actions performed on the item
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    return NO;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performAction:(SEL)action forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {

}
*/
```

@end

This do not work and is giving a:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
```

I did try "layoutIfNeeded" & "setNeedsDisplay" & "needsUpdateConstraints". And it has no effect? I I change the constraint(hightConstrint) right after it works, but not from the CodeBlock.

Also tried this:

```
hightConstraint.active = false;
hightConstraint.constant = 400;
hightConstraint.active = true;
```

The terminal logs the following:

```
2016-11-02 13:10:36.900317 FloatingButton[32486:1582882] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008ac30 FloatingView:0x7f98adc0a670.height == 100   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000087580 FloatingView:0x7f98adc0a670.height == 400   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000087580 FloatingView:0x7f98adc0a670.height == 400   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`This means that your view has too many constraints. There are some constraints that are causing your view to have conflicts when its trying to determine is position. Can you post the log showing which constraints are conflicting and are being broken?

Comment: Thanks, just updated with the logs. It just hits me; I did try first to remove the NSLayoutConstraint and re-adding it. But the log says "(active)>", maybe there some de-activation I should do?

Comment: Your `FloatingView`has 2 height constraints. Thats why its breaking the one being set to 400 and your height remains at 100. You should try and figure out how come two height constraints are being set and remove the one that is not required!

Comment: Yes, you are so right. Using https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html I did find more height constraints. And indeed it was just a simple problem causing symptoms :-) The problem was that I was setting my constraints in "setConstraints" from viewDidLayoutSubviews and this method is called twice :#

Comment: You could always try and set constraints in `viewWillAppear`or `viewDidAppear`. Just perform this check- `if([self isMovingToParentViewController] || [self isBeingPresented])`. This will ensure anything inside the if condition is only called once!

Answer (score 1):

When you change the value of a constraint (be it constant, in your case) you must call `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview of which that constraint applies to.

I assume that `floatingView` is what the constraint is attached to, in which case, call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`.

Though based on the code I see in your answer (maybe I am missing something though) you have 3 more problems:

1. You never add `floatingView` to your view controller's view.
2. You never add the constraint to `floatingView`.
3. You have other constraints which do not agree with what you are doing to that constraint. I'd recommend going over the logic of all your constraints and if need be drawing them out on a physical surface like a whiteboard (always helps me).

Comment: Thanks, I now have added all the code for the ViewController. I did try "layoutIfNeeded" & "setNeedsDisplay" & "needsUpdateConstraints". And it has no effect? I I change the constraint(hightConstrint) right after it works, but not from the CodeBlock.

Comment: Thanks for updating it. Are you sure the block is firing properly?

Comment: Yes, it is being called. This makes me think, could it be something to do with the thread running the CodeBlock?